# how can I remove a callback from $q.defer() promise object of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angularjs `$q.defer()` promise object receives notify callback, and when we give more than one, it keeps and notify all of them, i.e. it does not overwrite to older one.

```
var def=$q.defer();
def.promise.then(null, null, callback1);
def.promise.then(null, null, callback2);
```

Then if I want to remove (unregister), for example, `callback2`, what should I do?

Here is live example:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16177/)

Comment: Not sure you can, but how about adding an ``if`` conditional statement inside the callback that will check for the scenario of when you would like to "unregister" ?

Comment: @ItamarL. that is not a clean solution.

Comment: @MertMertce judging by the way you are describing your problem, it seems you what you really want is either an event bus or functional reactive programming rather than promise. Promise is there to chain a sequence of async calls. If you are looking for notifier, receiver, then you are looking at event bus. Try https://github.com/Gozala/events or http://reactivex.io/ I think you will really like ReactiveX.

Comment: angularjs already has $emit, $broadcast mechanisms. Please note that I don't ask alternatives. The question is just what it asks, if there is a way.

Comment: No, there is no supported manner of doing what you're asking.  What's your use case?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L3) for $q shows us that:

```
then: function(onFulfilled, onRejected, progressBack) {
  var result = new Deferred();

  this.$$state.pending = this.$$state.pending || [];
  this.$$state.pending.push([result, onFulfilled, onRejected, progressBack]);
  if (this.$$state.status > 0) scheduleProcessQueue(this.$$state);

  return result.promise;
}
```

So there is no specific identifier that would point to your anonymous callback in the `$$state.pending` stack in order to splice it out.

I haven't personally tried this before but if you wanted to wipe the pending stack, maybe `def.$$state.pending = [];` would do the trick. Then you could simply reassign only the `def.then()` callbacks you want.

Comment: Yes, but if only def.$$state does not have any other track of that. I had seen lots of siblings of pending. Seems dangerous but can be tried when to hold one callback is enough.

Comment: The only place where state.pending is directly accessed again is in `processQueue()` - and there it has a failsafe `for (var i = 0, ii = pending.length; i < ii; ++i)` where the length will be 0

Comment: So it seems that there is not an "official" way to do that, which makes what you have written the answer of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Promises are used to make a sequence of asynchronous processes. Once a step of this sequence is set, it's not possible (in an *elegant* way at least) to unset it.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's what you are trying to do here: you set a step with the callback2 and then you try to remove that step. Instead, I would recommend setting the callback2 only if a certain condition is fulfilled, for example:

```
var notifCallback;
if (true) {
    notifCallback = function(notif) {
        console.log('notify 1', notif);
    };
} else {
    notifCallback = function(notif) {
        console.log('notify 2', notif);
    };
}

def.promise.then(null, null, notifCallback);
```

[Example on jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16179/).